# Google chart : modify toopl tip

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, tooltip

I have a joint chart using google chart API. Here i want to update the tool tip of the chart.

As there is a lot of overlap in these charts i might not be able to actually hover over each discrete point and see data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `DataView` to provide a calculated column
which builds the tooltip for that row

see following snippet...

```
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(joinedData);
dataView.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return getTooltip(dt, row);
  },
  role: 'tooltip',
  type: 'string',
  p: {
    html: true
  }
}, 2, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return getTooltip(dt, row);
  },
  role: 'tooltip',
  type: 'string',
  p: {
    html: true
  }
}]);

function getTooltip(dt, row) {
  var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip">';
  tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0) + '</div>';

  tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(1) + '</div>';
  if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === null) {
    tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row + 1, 1) + '</div>';
  } else {
    tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + '</div>';
  }

  tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getColumnLabel(2) + '</div>';
  if (dt.getValue(row, 2) === null) {
    if (row > 0) {
      tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row - 1, 2) + '</div>';
    }
  } else {
    tooltip += '<div>' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2) + '</div>';
  }

  tooltip += '</div>';
  return tooltip;
}
```

---

full snippet --> http://jsfiddle.net/sqdfrf8f/1/

---

note: there is some sort of bug,
in that the chart will not respect column properties on data views
so the `html` property doesn't get set
the work around is to use data view method --> `toDataTable()`

also: need to use updated library for google charts, see --> [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)

Comment: the rows in the data posted here are staggered, not the case in the fiddle from the comment, as such, no need to adjust the row index, see this update --> [http://jsfiddle.net/sqdfrf8f/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/sqdfrf8f/5/)